# nginx reverse proxy caching with timestamp

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to cache the jpg and swf file with following URL request by IE

http://www.xxxx.com/abc.jpg?stamp=1388735064848

http://www.xxxx.com/def.swf?stamp=1388735064848

which stamp=[value] change every second

I have tried:

```
location ~* .(jpg|swf|)(\?stamp=[0-9.]+)?$ {
 {
    proxy_cache_valid 200 120m;
    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://IP;
 }
```

but it cannot work

Comment: not work mean when the stamp change, nginx cache it

Comment: If you want that nginx caches `abc.jpg?stamp=A` and `abc.jpg?stamp=B` as the same file `abc.jpg`, you should use directive `proxy_cache_key $uri;`.